# How can I validate that Steam Cloud is up to date?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud, elden-ring

I have previously played Elden Ring but found after a reinstall that some of my characters were lost, even though I am completely sure that before deleting the game for the reinstall, the cloud status showed 'Up to date'.

As this indicator is apparently not to be trusted, how can I verify that it is really up to date? For example, is there some way to download the files from the cloud so I can compare them to my local files?

Comment: Did you quit and reopen the Steam client before uninstalling? If so, was it a normal exit or did you force quit or use task manager -> end process? Any chance it could be related to daylight savings time change? Modern time algorithms are usually smart enough to handle minor differences like this, but it is an edge case and could be hard to even consider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Via a web browser, you can download your Steam Cloud saves at https://store.steampowered.com/account/remotestorage (note - there doesn't appear to be an actual link from within your account page, which is why I wrote the URL fully in this post).  The page should look something like this:

[image: Remote Storage]

From here, find the game you want, and click Show Files.  You can then download the files you wish and compare them using some external tool (perhaps a hex editor of some kind), or just by loading up the file and spotting any differences yourself!

[image: Files]

Comment: A bit like overkill, but `git diff old.save new.save` would quickly reveal differences in the saves, and there are GUI programs that can "diff" (aka compare) files in a more friendly way.